# Не работает функция Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сделал простую функцию, создающую локальную переменную url и выводя ее через print(url)

```
import requests
import misc
 
 
token = misc.token

URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/'


def get_updates():
    url =  URL + 'getupdates'
    print(url)



def main(): 
    get_updates()
```

Но, после того как я запускаю функцию в main(), ничего не происходит. Что делать?

Comment: у меня все работает

Comment: Что делать? вызвать функцию main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция main() не запускается автоматически.
Запусти ее

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__': это уже чрезмерая штука из модульного програмирования и в данном случае неуместна.

Comment: современное программирование практически полностью модульное. Прошли те времена, когда ты пишешь свой велосипед полностью в одном файле без использования библиотек. Поэтому не вижу ничего плохого в том, что заранее оставляешь возможность для расширения своего проекта. А использование `__name__ == '__main__'` всего лишь проверка, что твой проект запускается напрямую, а не используется в качестве модуля

Answer (score 0):

Запустите функцию main.

```
main()
```